# ie responseText is not complete

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a working upload progress bar in FF, Safari, but not IE.

Based on jquery.form, the form is submitted, but when the upload finishes, the PHP app sends out a whole new page, which is to be received in xhr.responseText. The the response is placed in a new document.

This works OK for FF, ...

On IE, the responseText begins with "\n   <table class=..." that is, the text inside the <body> tag (instead of the entire <html> ... </html> page.)

What's going on? what must I do to get IE to keep all the tags in the response?

UPDATE:

I am using:

- jQuery Form Plugin
- version: 3.35.0-2013.05.23

The jq to hook things up looks like:

```
    $('#JQF').ajaxForm({
      dataType:  'html',
      beforeSend: UP.start,
      success: UP.stop
    });

UP.stop:
function (html, status, xhr) {
  startTime = null;
  setTimeout(function () {
    jsonForm.success(html, status, xhr);
  }, 10);
}
```

and

```
jsonForm.success:
function(responseText, statusText, xhr, elt)
/*
1.) responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the dataType option).
2.) statusText
3.) xhr (or the jQuery-wrapped form element if using jQuery < 1.4)
4.) jQuery-wrapped form element (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)
) 
*/ {
  if (typeof responseText === 'string')
  {
    if (/<html>/i.test(responseText))
    {
      jsonForm.reloadMain(responseText);
    }
    else if (responseText)
    {
      alert(responseText);    <<<========== this is executed.
    }
  }
  else if (responseText && typeof responseText === 'object')
  {// decode and execute jquery instructions
    jsonForm.responseEval(responseText, {});
    jsonForm.init(); // in case we loaded something with a jsonForm in it
  }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

To turn off the use of an iframe, which constrains the return, one must include the ajaxForm option iframe: false.

Comment: Can we see some code? how are you getting the responseText?

Comment: If you're using jQuery I believe it uses a fragment to hold the elements, and fragments can't hold html/head/body tags, so they are normally filtered out. Not sure why it would work in Firefox ?

Comment: what contentType you are setting ?? (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')

Comment: Yeah, OK, I've updated the question to include code. I am asking for html and using the responseText that jquery returns to the success function.

Comment: OK, diving into tracing through jquery-form, it is deciding to use the iframe path (which it DID NOT decide to do with FF).

Comment: Now it returns the entire page string, but when I go to put it into  var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");  newDoc.write(html);
newDoc.close(); it chokes on undefined $, that is the jquery.

Comment: OK,the bottom line is that this is not necessary, as it does work to merely setTimeout(update, 2) and submit the form directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of wild goose chase.

It does work to start a script with setTimeout(updateinfo, 2); and then go ahead and submit a form.